# Sending received original JSON via cURL

Tags: php, json

I just want a little help.
So this is the scenario:

I have a php script that received a JSON and get it by file_get_contents function.
The json is send by API more likely like Glabs.
So for example I'll text the given shortcode for the API and it will send in json format and I'll be receiving it via PHP.

My question is, how can i send the original json format that i've received via cURL?
and receive it again by file_get_contents?is it possible?

Here is my sample script:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = stripslashes($json);
$values=json_decode($json,true);

$Msg=$values["inboundSMSMessageList"]["inboundSMSMessage"][0]["message"];
$dateTime=$values["inboundSMSMessageList"]["inboundSMSMessage"][0]["dateTime"];
$MPN=str_replace("tel:","",$values["inboundSMSMessageList"]["inboundSMSMessage"][0]["senderAddress"]);
```

That is my script for receiving a message sent from a mobile phone to  a shortcode then received by my script.
Thanks for who will help me

Comment: Where are you sending it? From your php script? Please post a complete, minimal working example so we can see what you're trying to do and suggest fixes.

Comment: Why are you calling `stripslashes`?

Comment: If you want to send the original JSON, just send `$json`.

Comment: Or you can send `json_encode($values)`. They should be the same.

Comment: thank you for your answers I have created a script for my problem. Anyway, thank you so much especially Mr.Barmar your last comment is really the cause to solve my problem thanks a lot